# search username in instagram by webdriver and show it in terminal

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I write a simple Instagram Bot that search username in search bar, but when I want to
Bot print the user name when found it, it doesn't work. Acually I can fix it with some if condition but I need to know why this code doesn't work:

```
'''
        # find search bar
        search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type = "text"]')
        search_input.clear()
        # send username to search
        search_input.send_keys(self.user_name)
        time.sleep(2)
        index = 0
        while index > 6:
            user_found = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_7UhW9.xLCgt.qyrsm.KV-D4.uL8Hv')[index]
            if user_found.text == self.user_name:
                print(user_found.text)
            index += 1
'''
```

the username I search is already exist
but program doesn't print it

Comment: Maybe they aren't equal print them out and see.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never run because of this:

```
    index = 0
    while index > 6:
        user_found = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_7UhW9.xLCgt.qyrsm.KV-D4.uL8Hv')[index]
        if user_found.text == self.user_name:
            print(user_found.text)
        index += 1
```

You set the index to 0, and then in while loop say "while index > 6".  It will never reach the while loop because it has been set to 0 to begin with

Comment: so what can i do?? I want to check it 6 times.

Comment: if you want to check it exactly 6 times than change it to:  while index <= 5: Then it will start at 0, and increment by 1 each loop.  0,1,2,3,4,5 and then stop.  That is 6 loops